# How to change default folder when SSH based on port?

Tags: linux, ssh, openssh

I am deploying my own server. I am facing a problem when working with SSH.
I have an user named **vhcguest**. Is it able to direct the default folder when this user ssh-ing my server based on the port? for example, if ssh-ing to port 2345 it will go to `/home/vhcguest/p1`; if ssh-ing to port 3456 it will go to `/home/vhcguest/p2`?

Thank you for all your explanations and answers.

Comment: Do you have full control over the configuration of the OpenSSH daemon on the server?

Comment: Yes, I am the owner of the server. Basically I want to open ssh on several ports, and then if access each port it will let the shell locate into each directory

Comment: Since I suspect you have two separate instances of OpenSSH running, have you tried using, `RemoteCommand cd /home/vhcguest/p2 && bash` within the configuration file to change the directory to the desired directory?

Comment: I have tried it, but I received an error from control process exited with error code. I added this line on the last of sshd_config file

Comment: I've not tried it, but  I posit you can set up ssh in a chroot jail on the alternative with an alternative root and passwd file.  Depending on your needs to traverse above the root directory you may need to set up some bind mounts as well.See https://www.tecmint.com/restrict-ssh-user-to-directory-using-chrooted-jail/